# JavaFx how to write text into specific position

Tags: java, javafx

This is my code:

```
public class Canvas extends Application {

@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new BorderPane();
        //...
        player = new Player();
        HBox topPanel = new HBox(currency);
        topPanel.setLayoutX(20);
        topPanel.setLayoutY(40);
        topPanel.setSpacing(40);
        root.setLeft(topPanel);

}
}
```

I want my currency number to be displayed on some specific position (not exactly top center) - based on other images in my application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Text` and set specific x and y coordinates for it.

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        int x = 50, y = 100;
        int currency = 10000;

        Text currencyText = new Text(x, y, String.valueOf(currency));

        Group root = new Group(currencyText);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```